# Not sure why my command doesn't work

Tags: apt, package-management, ppa, git

Edit: This post was marked as duplicate, I disagree that it is. My problem I suspect is not that a PPT is missing, the problem as I first stated is that a new PPT is missing each time I run the command. So the 1st time (7) isn't found, but the 2nd time (7) IS found but (5) isn't. 3rd time (4) isn't found but (7) and (5) are and so on.

Original: I'm trying to run the following command:

```
sudo apt update
```

And my output yields:

```
sebastian@sebastian-Lenovo-ideapad-S130-14IGM:~$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan InRelease
Hit:2 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates InRelease               
Ign:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gencfsm/ppa/ubuntu eoan InRelease               
Hit:4 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-backports InRelease             
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security InRelease [97,5 kB]      
Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan InRelease                          
Err:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gencfsm/ppa/ubuntu eoan Release                 
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Reading package lists... Done                             
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/gencfsm/ppa/ubuntu eoan Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
sebastian@sebastian-Lenovo-ideapad-S130-14IGM:~$
```

I looked at some similar posts and they mentioned a faulty or somehow incorrect proxy. I am not using a proxy. And the stranger thing is that the package that keeps failing is different everytime I run the command, and it's always only one package that fails.

Any ideas?

Comment: A "does not have a release file" error has nothing to do with proxies. You might be focusing on the wrong part of the error message during your searches.

Comment: That one PPA does not support Eoan, so it's 404ing because it has no Release file to govern Eoan.  You need to remove the PPA.

Comment: Guys the problem isn't that the package doesn't exist, the problem is that the package that doesn't exist keeps changing each time I run the command. 1st run gives error for (7), second time gives error for (5) etc.

Comment: "And the stranger thing is that the package that keeps failing is different everytime I run the command, and it's always only one package that fails. " That was my original post, I have since edited because it wasn't clear enough. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

A "does not have a release file" error in a PPA means that there are no packages for your release of Ubuntu. So stop trying to use it.

Disable or delete that PPA.

Comment: Alright but, each time I run the command the "does not have a release file error" for (7) changes to (3) or (6) or (5) etc. Strange, no?

Comment: No, does not seem strange at all.

Comment: My friend I'm clearly missing something, do you mind explaining why that isn't strange?

Comment: Check three of four runs of output: Replies from the sources will often be in different order. Your other sources are very unlikely to have that particular error.